# Function to remove specific word from lists

Tags: python, list, function

I have several lists that contain the word 'Data' at varying locations in the list. I'd like to build a function that removes just that word (not the whole element) from each list.

```
example_list = ['Client 1 Data','Client 2','Client 3 Data']

output_list = ['Client 1','Client 2','Client 3']
```

I've tried this but it is not working:

```
def my_func(column):
    for i in range(len(column)):
        column.replace('Data', '')
```

Comment: Please specify what is meant by "not working"

Comment: `column` is the list, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `replace` returns a modified string, it doesn't modify the original string.  If you want to modify the list, you need to call `replace` on each individual string and assign the modified strings to the indices in the original list:

```
>>> def my_func(column):
...     for i in range(len(column)):
...         column[i] = column[i].replace('Data', '')
...
>>> example_list = ['Client 1 Data','Client 2','Client 3 Data']
>>> my_func(example_list)
>>> example_list
['Client 1 ', 'Client 2', 'Client 3 ']
```

If modifying the original list inside the function isn't a requirement, it's actually easier to do this by building and returning a new list:

```
>>> def my_func(column):
...     return [entry.replace('Data', '') for entry in column]
...
>>> my_func(['Client 1 Data','Client 2','Client 3 Data'])
['Client 1 ', 'Client 2', 'Client 3 ']
```

Another option is to build the new list inside the function (e.g. via comprehension) and then assign it into the original list via a slice assignment:

```
>>> def my_func(column):
...     column[:] = [entry.replace('Data', '') for entry in column]
...
>>> example_list = ['Client 1 Data','Client 2','Client 3 Data']
>>> my_func(example_list)
>>> example_list
['Client 1 ', 'Client 2', 'Client 3 ']
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def remove_word(words: list[str], word_to_remove: str) -> list[str]:
    return [w.replace(word_to_remove, '').strip() for w in words]


def main() -> None:
    example_list = ['Client 1 Data', 'Client 2', 'Client 3 Data']
    print(f'{example_list = }')
    output_list = remove_word(words=example_list, word_to_remove='Data')
    print(f'{output_list = }')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
example_list = ['Client 1 Data', 'Client 2', 'Client 3 Data']
output_list = ['Client 1', 'Client 2', 'Client 3']
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use map on `list` but if you want correct your code, you need to specify which index you want to change:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: x.replace('Data', ''), example_list))
['Client 1 ', 'Client 2', 'Client 3 ']
```

Your Code:

```
def my_func(column):
    for i in range(len(column)):
        column[i] = column[i].replace('Data', '')
```

Output:

```
my_func(example_list)
print(example_list)
# ['Client 1 ', 'Client 2', 'Client 3 ']
```